# “No files were changed or added since the last commit. There's nothing for TortoiseSVN to do here...”

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

We are using Tortoise SVN and have come to a problem when trying to commit modified files.
When we try to commit the file svn does not recognise that it has been modified or added and displays 
“No files were changed or added since the last commit. There's nothing for TortoiseSVN to do here...”
The only way we can now commit one file is to go out to the folder and select “check for modifications” and then click to commit.
If the check for modifications is done in the folder then is again says there are no modifications.
We have also tried to create a fresh working copy and commit from there, however the problem occurs here too.
We have tried copying the svn file incase it was corrupt but this did not help.
We use the SVN icons to show when a file has been modified – these icons are still working correctly.
We have searched for an answer to why this has happened and how to fix. Please could anyone spread any light on the matter.

Comment: Explain in detailed, bullet-point steps (preferably with screenshots) how you "try to commit modified files". You don't really go into any detail here. Also I think you're off-topic.

Comment: They are word documents which we edit in word. We save the document, the svn icon goes red. Normally, we right click on the document that has been modified and choose the 'svn commit' option, it then comes up with a pop up box and we write a comment about why we are committing it before choosing ok, it never used to say that the file was not modified unless it wasnt. HOWEVER, now it always says it isn't modified even when it is and won't let us commit. The only way to commit now, is to right click on the folder that the doc is in, tortoise svn, check for modifications.

Comment: When checking for modifications, a pop up box is open with a list of modified files including the document we have just modified, committing the document from here works fine. So the document is definitely modified, for some reason SVN is not recognising the document as modified when using the other method?

Answer (score 5):

From the [FAQ](http://tortoisesvn.net/faq.html#detectmodification):

If you have modified a file, but TortoiseSVN does not recognize that the file has been modified, please first check whether the file really differs from what you have in your working copy.

If you know for sure that the file has modifications and it still does not show up as modified in the commit dialog, make sure that

- the file 'last modification' date has changed (some tools like hex editors like to reset that time)
- if the svn:eol-style property is set and the changes are only to newlines, the file won't show up as modified because for Subversion it hasn't changed

Subversion determines whether a file has changed with the following approach:

1. has the 'last modification' date and/or the file size changed?
2. if not: file is not modified
3. if yes: compare file content with the BASE file
4. stop at the first byte that differs, mark the file as modified
5. if no byte differs regarding to BASE, mark the file as not-modified

Comment: The files are modified, the base file is different.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to press enter then. When you check for modifications it also works correctly at this point and knows that the file has been modified and allows you to commit at this point. The last modification date and file size is also different. We have used SVN for some time now and not had this error before, unfortunately can not see any way round troubleshooting this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5):

Just in case anyone else finds their way here. I've just experienced this same problem with a repository that had been working fine for some time. The files were showing that they contained changes, but SVN Commit.. gave the message that there were no commits to make.

It was caused by a subfolder that I had copied into my repository. The subfolder had been created in an older version of tortoise. Once I selected the tortoise option to update it to the latest version, SVN Commit worked as expected.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. I had an SVN external with an issue. If you do an SVN cleanup or SVN update you should get an error which will point you to the external with the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar but not identical problem. I know this stream is 4 years ago but for the record in case anyone else searches. (I am on tortoise SVN version 1.8.x).

My modified files would not commit - same symptom as presented in this stream. I right clicked on the project and selected "Clean Up". Thereafter I could commit my modified files.

Answer (score 0):

Open you project->Right click
Click on that Disconnect then  Do the usual work like share project using SVN and commit it.